# Spring RestController: custom date format for java.time.LocalDate does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I would like to change the default date format for the JSON serializer in my Spring-boot application. It seems that I really missed something because none of the following methods can work for me: [5 ways to customize Spring MVC JSON/XML output](https://mostafa-asg.github.io/post/customize-json-xml-spring-mvc-output/)

**Environment:**

- Java 11
- Spring boot: 2.1.6.RELEASE

**My relevant dependencies:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**POJO:**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    ...

    @ApiModelProperty(example = "2019/01/01", notes = "date of birth as YYYY/MM/DD")
    @Past(message = "Are you really from the future?")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
}
```

**Spring configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class OutputConfiguration {

    private static final String PATTERN = "yyyy/MM/dd";

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.createXmlMapper(false).build();
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat(pattern));
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

If I add `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy/MM/dd")` into the POJO, before the `LocalDate` variable then everything works fine. But because I have a lot of `LocalDate` variables I would like to add this configuration to the application level.

**This is the error I get:**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2019/05/29": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019/05/29' could not be parsed at index 4; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String "2019/05/29": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '2019/05/29' could not be parsed at index 4
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.remal.gombi.component.domain.User["dateOfBirth"])
```

What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

If I add the following configuration, then the GET rest request returns with a properly formatted LocalDate: `"dateOfBirth": "29/05/2019"`, BUT the POST method still expects the ISO date format: `"dateOfBirth": "2019-01-01"`. It is so strange.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder customJacksonMapper() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .indentOutput(true)
            .serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DATE_PATTERN)));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `spring.jackson.date-format=yyyy/MM/dd` in `application.properties`? This and other `Jackson Properties` can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

Comment: According to [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates), the @JsonFormat should be enough.

Comment: You can also write you own application level Seriliazer and add it using `@JsonSerialize`